# Curl Localhost Issue in Mac Terminal

Tags: terminal

I'm getting the error

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

when I execute the command

```
curl localhost
```

in Mac terminal.

My /etc/hosts file content

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Start a webserver that listens on port 80.

Comment: how will that fix the issue ? can u explain

Comment: The purpose of `curl localhost` is to perform a HTTP GET request to the webserver running on localhost, similar to what entering `http://localhost/` into your browsers address bar would do. "Connection refused" means that no such server is running, and so starting one will solve the problem.